# User can't authenticate while download file using Office 365 API

Tags: office365

I created web project for getting files and download files from office 365 in Visual studio 2013 with office 365 API, I am able to see all the files from specific location but when I try to download specific file I am getting below error

The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset

Please help on it..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is something wrong with the implementation of the cache that they use in the Authenticator. But luckily you can replace it with your own cache implementation. I did so in my sample: https://github.com/sjkp/Office365APITools/blob/master/Office365APIToolsSample/

It’s a little involved, as you have to create you own authenticator

```
Authenticator<FixedSessionCache>
```

and specific the new and fixed cache, you also have to change the OAuthRedirectHandler in the web.config to this one that uses the new cache.

```
      <add name="OAuth2RedirectHandler" verb="GET" path="/c5bee8be-77e8-41bc-a0b7-f901b00f3dd6.axd" type="Office365APIToolsSample.OAuth2RedirectHandler, Office365APIToolsSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
```

Please note if you use my sample code then you have to update the password in the appsettings in the web.config